# Angular Response Interceptor--Handling Promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have created the interceptor below--it basically redirects to a known location when the service sends a response indicating that the user's session has expired.

It currently works correctly--what I'm not sure about is whether to reject the promise, return the response, or do something different.  If I just redirect, it works as expected.  If I reject the promise, I end up in the error handler of the ajax call (not shown), but it otherwise successfully redirects.

What is the correct way to fulfill the promise in this scenario?

**Edit:** Added the else clause.

```
    var responseInterceptor = function ($q) {
        return function (promise) {
            return promise.then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.SessionHasExpired == true) {
                    window.location.href = "/Home/Login?message=User session has expired, please re-login.";
                    return $q.reject(response); //do I need this?  What to do here?
                }
                else {
                    return response;
                }

            }, function (response) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            });
        };
    };
```

Comment: The server should probably not be responding successfully (HTTP 200) if the session has expired. It would be better to have it respond with a [401 Unauthorized](http://httpstatus.es/401) status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a case, I think you should handle the error inside the error callback, and only reject the promise if the error isn't something you were expecting. I mean, deal with the session timeout error and reject the promise for everything else. If you reject it even after handling the error, all errors callbacks related to the promise will be invoked (as you've noticed yourself) and none of them will handle the session timeout error (after all, you have made an interceptor for doing precisely that).

I support the @idbehold advice of using a more appropriate status code for this situation. `401 Unauthorized` is the way to go.

With all of this being considered, your code could look like this:

```
var responseInterceptor = function($q) {
    return function(promise) {
        var success = function(response) { 
            return response; 
        };
        var error = function(response) {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                window.location.href = "/Home/Login?message=User session has expired, please re-login.";
            }
            else {
                return $q.reject(response);                    
            }
        };
        return promise.then(success, error);
    };
};
```

Perhaps you'd be interested in checking out [this](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) Angular module on Github.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into seeing if the server can return a 401.

Comment: In the case of the 401, it's best to still return the $q.reject(response) after the redirect. This way, there will be no error in the JS console (even though it's only temporary, seeing as the page is immediately redirected).